# How to remove Parentheses from a string

Tags: python

The following code results in a string that I want to remove:

```
with open('company_inf1.csv', 'rb') as inf :
    reader = csv.reader(inf, delimiter=',')
    reader.next() #skip header
    for i,row in enumerate(reader):
        name, date, indus, nike1, nike2, nike3, paid, abbr = row
        t = (map(str, (nike1, nike2, nike3)),) # map & merge the 3 cols together\
        b = str(t) [1:-1]
        c = b.replace('"', '\\"')
        print( name, date, indus, b , paid, abbr)
```

My output is

```
 ('abc', '30-06-1987', 'Service', "['nike1', 'nike2', 'nike3 '],", '100',
 'abs')
```

I also want to remove the double quotes, so that the output become:

```
<output missing from OP>
```

I have already tried with `replace` and `strip` commands, but it did not work for me. I also want to save the test where I am printing the value of `b` into a test file. How can I do this?

Comment: I think the main reason this question have been down-voted, is because the title doesn't reflect the final question(s). The title question is still good, and a new answer addressing that may be more helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to map to string, because its already a string when it comes out of the file.

You can do `b = [nike1, nike2, nike3]`, or:

```
with open('company_inf1.csv', 'rb') as inf :
    reader = csv.reader(inf, delimiter=',')
    reader.next() #skip header
    name, date, indus, nike1, nike2, nike3, paid, abbr = row
    print(name, date, indus, [nike1, nike2, nike3], paid, abbr)
```

Answer (score 3):

To remove the parenthesis from a simple "string" you can use:

```
import re
...
re.sub(r'[\(\)]', '', str(mystring))
```

However, if it's an array, you need to employ something like:

```
p = re.compile(r'[\(\)]')
list = [p.sub(' ', x).strip() for x in array]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
print (value[0] + value[1] + "(" + value[2] + ")")
```